# SQL subquery that returns more than one column

Tags: php, sql, subquery

I am trying to execute what I think is an easy SQL statement, but I am receiving an error when I try and use a subquery saying that more than one column is being returned, but I need more than one column to be returned.

I am just trying to show two columns, my user's name, and their current balance

Here is the SQL:

```
SELECT playid, username, balance FROM plays order by playid desc limit 25
```

Which returns:

```
Play ID Username    Balance

593     ken     -3497

592     cass    -204

591     cass    -184

590     cass    -164

589     ken     -517

580     ken     -837

579     sam      250

545     cass    -134

544     cass    -114
```

Which is exactly what I want. A list of all my members, and their balances. Now I need to run a SUBQUERY on this query, to only select the balance with the highest Id (The most recent balance) Which would return a table like this:

```
Play ID Username    Balance

593     ken     -3497

592     cass    -204

579     sam      250
```

The most recent balance is the only thing that I am concerned with. When I try and execute this second query, I get an error saying that I am trying to return multiple columns. (which I am of course)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you need to clarify what you want as your output. The last table you drew does not align with your written description of what you want.

Comment: What is your second query

Comment: The output of the second table is exactly what I want. The Play ID of the user, the username and the balance. The most current balance is going to have the highest playID. Everytime the balance is adjusted for each user, the playID increases, so therefore I don't care about older balances. I'm not sure if I even need a subquery for this statement. Ideally I'd like to use some kind of username DISTINCT statement but that doesn't work.

Comment: Blip means the query - not the result. It would be something like `SELECT ... FROM ...`

Comment: Well this is my question. How do I query the first table to do something like SELECT DISTINCT username to remove the erroneous usernames and only arrive with ONE username, and ONE balance which is the balance with the highest playID.

Comment: You stated that you were getting an error from your query - what was that query? I provided and answer based on your expected output (table in question) and not explicitly from your description because I think they are contradicting each other. Either you want ONE username and ONE balance (as in your description) or you want THREE as in your table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: You've now mentioned this is for MySQL. Try this:

```
SELECT
    p1.playid,
    p1.username,
    p1.balance
FROM
    plays p1
JOIN
    (
    SELECT
        MAX(playid) AS playid,
        username
    FROM
        plays
    GROUP BY
        username
    ) p2
    ON  (p2.username = p1.username)
    AND (p2.playid = p1.playid);
```

-
This is probably what you are looking for. I assume you want the most recent balance *by username* based on the play id:

```
SELECT
    playid,
    username,
    balance
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        playid,
        username,
        balance,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY username ORDER BY playid DESC) AS seq
    FROM
        plays
    ) base
WHERE
    seq = 1
```

This sequences the records by username, on playid descending, then returns the most recent record for each.

Comment: This returned an error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(PARTITION BY username ORDER BY playid DESC) AS seq
    FROM
        plays
    )' at line 11  but I think this is what I need. I'll keep plugging away at it. Thanks.

Comment: MySQL does not have that function, unfortunately - this is why it is important to tag/mention the DBMS you are using................

Comment: See the update and let me know how it fares with you.

Comment: It works perfectly. Thank you so much. This was my first post, I'll be sure to tag things correctly for the next time. Thanks again!